# How to lazy load static JSON in angular application

Tags: json, angular, lazy-loading, assets

I want to know how can we lazy load JSON files in angular application. As per my understanding, static content in assets folder is loaded by default at the time of initial rendering only and is present in browser memory. I want only specific JSON files to be loaded in browser on demand. Can someone please explain how to do that.

Comment: _As per my understanding, static content in assets folder is loaded by default at the time of initial rendering only and is present in browser memory_ where did you got this from?

Comment: I placed some JSON files in asset folder. In my HTML i put a button, on clicking which some attributes of this JSON will be displayed. While running application on IE i checked memory, before and after clicking the button. It did not change significantly. Also i came across strategies which need to be implemented explictly if we want to lazy load the assets. So i concluded that by default, the assets must be loaded in browser at the time of initial loading, before requested. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: In your example, if you imported that JSON into your component file then of course it won't be lazily loaded as the import statement is resolved on the build step. Update your question with a concrete use case. But I can almost totally sure tell you that your understanding is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Jota, this helped clear my understanding. I had imported the file. Now i am trying to access the JSONs as an HTTP resource with their URL on click inside my .ts file  and i can see the JSON appear in network tab in dev tools on clicking the button. Hence i can conclude that the JSONs are being lazily-loaded on demand.

Answer (score 1):

It is not mandatory to place all your static content inside assets folder of the app module. you can create assets folder at module level. so that those content will be loaded when the module is loaded.

```
app/
    modules/
        module_1/
            assets/
                images/
                    image_module_1.png
            module_1.component.ts
            module_1.module.ts
        module_2/
            assets/
                images/
                    image_module_2.png
            module_2.component.ts
            module_2.module.ts
    app.module.ts
```

In case of above hierarchy if module_2 is lazy loaded then the assets will also be downloaded when module is loaded.

Comment: Thanks Yash. Please have a look at the above comments with the question. I suppose no need for any specific solution here as angular loads the required assets only. Rest all resources are loaded on demand. This seems to be the default behavior.